# Making a div scrollable inside a resizeable container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div that looks like the MS Windows Command Prompt.

The div is resizeable, and has two children: a title-bar div, and a content div.

I want the content div to get scrollbars when it is larger than the window div.  I want the title-bar to always be visible and not scroll, and not to be on top of the scroll bars.

[image]

http://www.webdevout.net/test?0vL interactively demonstrates my problem.  Click on the content text and new rows get added.  When enough rows are added for scroll bars to appear, they do not.

The content div has `overflow:auto` set.

Setting `max-height` or `height` on the content to `100%` does not work because 100% doesn't account for the title-bar height, so the scrollbars appear after some rows have gone off the bottom.  Also, the scrollbars, when they appear, obscure the draggable thumb on the outer div, stopping it being resizeable :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your resizable window to the child 'content' `<div>`. that way you're resizing the child `<div>` and the parent `<div>` resizes automatically to hold its contents.

Also, not sure if it was intentional but you have `<div id ="Content" class="Content">` in your html and `.Frame>.Contents {` in your CSS (note the word content has an 's' in the CSS).

I believe this is what you're looking for:

http://www.webdevout.net/test?0wE

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS:

```
.Content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Here you go: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0v-

Cheers ;)

Comment: I've added a description of why this doesn't work to the question.  The scrollbars appear after the content is bigger than the container, not the remaining space :(  Also, it stops it being resizeable :(

Comment: Did you check the my link? It works perfectly for me. Could you please elaborate if it still doesn't work as you want it to or provide a link where we can see the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Would you like the scrollbar to appear at all time? If yes then use `overflow-x: visible;` instead.

Comment: yes, your link's solution doesn't work for me :( I'm on Chrome OSX.  As soon as a text line only partially visible, I want the scrollbar to appear.  100% of the parent div is not the space for the content; there's a title bar too.  Also when the scrollbar appears, you can no longer drag on the corner of the outer div to resize everything.

Comment: If you add enough lines for the scrollbars to appear, and you scroll to the bottom of using the scrollbar, do you get a completely visible final line shown?  I do not.  Perhaps this most easily explains what I mean?

Comment: Haaaa OK now I understand what you mean. Well there is no easy solution for that, unless you set the content's height manually. Regarding the drag-corner-being-hidden-by-the-scrollbar issue, how would you like to solve it? We could move the scrollbar to the left by 10px, for example.

Comment: I'd be prepared to use JS if necessary (no libraries, just raw JS).  How would I do that though?  To get the thumb visible, might work to make both scrollbars always visible so that the corner is not occupied.  But generally I'd like dragging on the side of the window to resize it, and not just one corner.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your HTML tree looks like:

- Dialog

  - Title bar
  - Content

To make the Content scrollable, use the `overflow` CSS property

```
.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: The suggested CSS doesn't work on his example. This is because his .Content div container is not being resized, therefore the scroll is not being triggered. The div's height extends infinitely and is being hidden. So we need to make sure to limit the div's height first, see my answer ;)

Comment: @usernotfound I see. There was no information about the resizing when I posted this answer. I used your example to correct this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add the CSS property

```
overflow:auto;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your CSS

`overflow: auto;`