# Resizeable: Resize div smaller than contents and make scrollable

Tags: jquery, css, resizable, scrollable

I have 2 divs that need to be resizable to the left and right(and fill up eachothers space).
The divs need to become scrollable, when they become too small for their content. My problem is: When the width of content inside the resizables is set eg. canvas width='200' , that resizable div won't resize smaller than the canvas.
Here is the fiddle:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jenietos/o8djk8f)

I already looked here:
[Making a div scrollable inside a resizeable container div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377559/making-a-div-scrollable-inside-a-resizeable-container-div)

and wrapped another div : .inner around contents and set it to width :inherit

```
.inner{width:inherit;  }

    .pane {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;`enter code here`
    overflow:auto;
}
.left.pane {
   background-color: olivedrab; 
}


.right.pane {
    background-color: orange;  
}
canvas{width:200px ; border:solid 1px red}
```

I also tried the following, but it only works if left-pane width is not 'fixed' with a pre:

```
resize: function(e, ui) {
           var dif= ui.originalSize.width - ui.size.width;
            console.log(dif +'   '+ ui.originalSize.width);
          var oldWidth= $(".right.pane").width();
            $(".right.pane").width( oldWidth + dif);
        }
```

It also reacts to strong, and becomes very unpleasant to use.

I think that somehow I should be able to override the rule that a resizable does not resize smaller than contents.(I am not able to resize the width of contents, they should just be scrollable)

I've tried the following: but that didn't work

```
.inner{width:auto; min-width:inherit; max-width:inherit;  or 0% 100% respectively}
```

Making both right and left divs resizable doesn't work either + leaves unwanted gaps.

How can I resize the panes smaller than their contents, and make the panes scrollable.

Help is really appreciated.
Jenita

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer to my question...

Comment: It isn't an answer, it was a comment. Please check your demo on jsFiddle.net, it's a 404 which means the link leads you to a non-existent webpage.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jenietos/o8djk8ft/5/     sorry about that, I didn't realize the link name changes when you revise it. This one should work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the scrollbars to appear on both divs: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/obry4wbd/)
I made canvas 100% width and made the div.left.pane the parent of .inner

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
 header    
</div>
   <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class='left pane'> <div class="inner"><pre>  Left
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bal

  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bal

  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bal
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bal
           </pre>    
       </div> </div>

       <div class="right pane">Right
       <div class='inner'> 
           <canvas > </canvas>
       </div>
       </div> 
       </div>

      <div class="footer">
  Footer  
</div>   
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
display: table;
 height:75%;
 width:90%;
    background-color: red;
}

.header {
    height: 5%;
    background-color: moccasin;  
}
.inner-wrapper{
display: table;
    overflow:auto;
width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}

.pane {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
.left.pane {
   background-color: olivedrab; 
}
.inner{width:auto; min-width:inherit; max-width:inherit;}

.right.pane {
    background-color: orange;  
}
canvas{width:100% ; border:solid 1px red}
.footer {
    height: 5%;
    background-color: moccasin;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The left side  (with pre tag) still does not resize , and also I actually don't want the canvas to change shape, because it will contain games, and it's better if the user can see the game (in original state) while looking at the code in the pre tag. Is it possible to override resizable()s behaviour to limit resizing to set widths, or should I use another plug in

Comment: Personally, I'd keep plugins to a minimum with layouts. If you're interested in an alternate solution, I would give flexbox a try. Let me know if you need help. As for the resizer, it doesn't seem to function outside of the fiddle. I tried using it on a separate page with the same versions: jquery 1.9.1 and jquery ui 1.9.2.  I tried with the current versions as well with no luck.